# Does node.js clean itself up after requests?

Tags: node.js

I read that node.js is single-threaded, so it doesn't fork a new process or start a new thread for each http request. But then does the http module have a way of cleaning up after it closes each connection? For example, if I create an object inside the callback every time someone requests a page, does that object get destroyed once the response is served and the connection is closed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes this true is due to scoping.

```
http.createServer(function(res) {
  var localobject = new BigObject();
  ...
  res.end();
});
```

Once you end the function the BigObject is no longer in use and gets cleaned up by the garbage collector.

Comment: You can also speed things along by doing a `localobject = null;`

Comment: I don't think setting a local reference on an object to null will help speed up garbage collection... ^